# Electric infloor heat with solid hardwood floors - should the wood feel warm?

Tags: heating, radiant-heating

I am using Warmly Yours infloor electric heating cables, as well as Mysa thermostats.

On the same 240v circuit, I have a bathroom (tile) and a kids bedroom (solid hardwood floor). Ohms we’re tested before, during and after installation (before final hookup of Mysa thermostat.) a circuit check was in place and never went off for either system. The two infloor electric heating systems, while on the same circuit back to my electric panel, are separate cables / thermisters / thermostats.

The Mysa thermostat reports that both are working just fine.

The tile bathroom one, however, you can feel the heat on your feet. That is comprised of the Warmly Yours cable in LevelQuick self-leveling, Hardybacker on that and then the tile. Works perfectly.

The hardwood however, which is the cable in self-leveling between furring strips, and then the hardwood directly on top of that. You just don’t really feel the heat in the wood there though, at all.

So the question is, would this be normal? Is wood just better at dispersing / spreading out the heat than tile?

Comment: Just for fun. What is under the heater in the hardwood floor room

Comment: Had water pipes under wood to heat a floor - commercial setting and worked well. Design for the conditions, also water in pipes never exceeded 35 deg C.

Comment: @Ruskes 5 / 8" T&G OSB, and no insulation in the joists (both of these rooms are on the second floor.)

Comment: ideally a room's air and floor would be the same temp. if the floor is warmer, your room is losing heat somewhere. you also describe human factors of perception; a 50F evening is brisk, a 50F pond is deadly because water conducts heat so much better than air.

Comment: Someone should have told you that before spending money on installing heaters under hardwood floors.

Comment: @dandavis  all structures will lose heat. I they didn't there would be no need for heating/cooling systems. Even super insulated homes require a heat source. If the floor is the same temp as the room, it's not doing anything to warm the room or keep it up to set point. Most hydronic heating systems require the floor to be several degrees above ambient temp to be effective.  In very cold climates that may even be 10-15 F above ambient.     In my home I have radiant hydronic thru-out,  (tile, wood and carpet) and it works great everywhere. It's quite nice to have a warm floor in stocking feet.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I agree with all that, nothing's ideal. the wood could very well be hotter than the tile yet feel cooler because wood doesn't conduct heat that well. I've seen a video about the special foamy tiles they coat the space shuttle with; they can be glowing hot and picked up with a bare hand because they conduct so little heat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tile will always be a better conductor of in floor heating than wood.  The more important question is: "are both rooms getting to desired set-point?" If so, you don't have a problem.

Comment: How do you know that ?

Comment: @Ruskes personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

The floor feeling warm is actually a sign your room isn't well insulated:

The underfloor heating has to compensate for heat losses. These depend on the quality of your insulation. The worse your insulation is, the more your thermostat will have to crank up the power, and that makes the floor feel warmer. If your insulation is good, it will maintain the desired temperature while feeling barely warm.

If the underfloor heating manages to keep the temperature at the desired setpoint and the floor doesn't feel warm, it just means your insulation is good enough.

Comment: Interesting. Both of these rooms are on a second floor. There is no insulation in the joists below them. The bedroom with wood flooring has two 2x6 exterior walls, the bathroom with tile has about 5 ½' of exterior 2x6 exterior wall, and then some fire & sound insulation in its walls. In general, this is a brand new home with impeccable insulation (think dozens of bottles of caulk, 2x6 walls fully insulated to R-23, R-38 in the ceiling.)

Comment: Yeah your good insulation explains it I guess. And perhaps the thermostat is set to a higher temperature in the bathroom too!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the Thermal conductivity of materials:

Porcelain (tiles) 1.5 W/(m.K)

Oak wood 0.17 W/(m.K) (10 times less heat conductive)

Comparison to insulators (acting as heat barriers)

Fiberglass 0.048 W/(m.K)

Polyurethane foam 0.024 W/(m.K)